# How to separate local storage values and display them in vertical order in HTML

Tags: html, local-storage

I have a local storage values and when i display them in an HTML page they look like this:

[image]

I want them to appear in vertical order like this:

[image]

Code:

```js
//page script
document.querySelector('#record').innerHTML =  localStorage.getItem("history")


//original data
var val = data.id + ':' +' ' + data.message + " " +'[' + new Date().toUTCString() + ']';
var callback = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("history")) || [];
callback.push(val);
localStorage.setItem("history", JSON.stringify(callback));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
      <link rel="icon" href="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/google/241/speech-balloon_1f4ac.png">
   </head>
   <title>Chat50 | History</title>
   
   <h2 class="display-3" style="color: whitesmoke; text-align: center;">Chat History Record </h2>
   <body class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #21252b;">
      <div class="jumbotron" id="record" style="background-color: #282c34;">      
      </div>
   </body>
```

Local storage values:

```
0: "dev:  [Wed, 26 Aug 2020 06:07:55 GMT]"
1: "dev: asd [Wed, 26 Aug 2020 06:07:57 GMT]"
2: "dev: has connected [Wed, 26 Aug 2020 06:07:58 GMT]"
3: "dev: oi [Wed, 26 Aug 2020 06:07:59 GMT]"
4: "dev: wow [Wed, 26 Aug 2020 06:08:00 GMT]"
```

Comment: is it a string?

Comment: post you code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you,

```js
const string = localStorage.getItem('history');
const array = JSON.parse(string);

const ul = document.createElement('ul');
let data = '';
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const text = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
// assuming you have id of 'root' where you want to display these items
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear. It looks like you want to display the `localstorage` items in more like JSON data instead of one liner.  Use `pre` tag to achieve that. And if you want to display the items in different divs then you have to go through a loop and add your content.

HTML:

```
<pre id="formattedJson"></pre>
```

JS:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("history");

document.getElementById("formattedJson").textContent = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

Comment: still horizontal but with scroll bar

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add proper data whatever you are getting from `localstorage` and what you want as an output. Don't add pictures in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate `'<br/>'` inside your script like:

```
document.querySelector('#record').innerHTML =  localStorage.getItem("history") + '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to display it like a chat log in your HTML you have to iterate through each element in the array and then render it to the DOM. You can use `.classList.add('myClassName')` to add CSS classes

```js
const data =["dev:has connected [Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:05:07 GMT]","dev: okay boomer[Wed, 26 Aug 2020 05:05:44 GMT]"]

const message_list = document.querySelector('#messages')

data.forEach(message=>{

let message_section = document.createElement('div')
let message_time = document.createElement('span');
let line_break = document.createElement('br');
let message_data = document.createElement('span')

message_data.textContent = message.split('[')[0]
message_time.textContent = message.split('[')[1].replace(']','')


message_section.appendChild(message_data);
message_section.appendChild(line_break)
message_section.appendChild(message_time);

message_list.appendChild(message_section)

});
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>My Chat History</h1>
  <section id='messages'>
    <!--Where all my messages will go -->
  </section>

</section>
```